# Dissimilar vs. Different

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Could someone please tell me whether it is possible to use ***Dissimilar*** and ***Different*** interchangeably?

> Belief, concept and opinion may be **different** from individual to individual.

Can we replace the word 'Different' with the word 'Dissimilar' in the above sentence without changing it's meaning?

Comment: More idiomatically, *X, Y, and Z may **differ** from person to person*. And there's no equivalent verb form derived from ***[dis]similar.***

Comment: ... Yes, a sentence being grammatical doesn't guarantee that any fluent Anglophone would actually use it. 'Dissimilar' and 'different' are obviously synonyms (which means that there _are_ sentences where they may be interchanged with no or negligible change in meaning, major connotations, and idiomaticity), but the words are not _generally_ interchangeable. For a start, 'dissimilar' is of a far more formal register. It is (perhaps largely as a result) far less common. // The only way to get a feel for idiomaticity is to examine / encounter a lot of well-written example sentences.

Comment: _Dissimilar_ and _different_ are adjectives. _Difference_ is a noun.

Comment: @KateBunting Sorry, typing error. I meant dissimilar vs. different, not dissimilar vs. difference.